# jsPDF isn't working with Django - Render HTML page to PDF

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, pdf-generation, jspdf

I was using this function below to generate and download the pdf version of such a page.

```
<script>
        function getPDF() {

            var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
            var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
            var top_left_margin = 15;
            var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
            var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

            var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;


            html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0], {
                allowTaint: true
            }).then(function(canvas) {
                canvas.getContext('2d');

                console.log(canvas.height + "  " + canvas.width);


                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);


                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
                    pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
                }

                pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Here is an example when the function worked:

```
<button onclick="getPDF()" id="downloadbtn" style="display: inline-block;"><b>Click to Download HTML as PDF</b></button>
<div class="canvas_div_pdf" style="margin-left:100px;">
<p> Something to render.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

But when I try to use Django variables, like below, it doesn't work, I click on the button and nothing happened:

```
<button onclick="getPDF()" id="downloadbtn" style="display: inline-block;"><b>Click to Download HTML as PDF</b></button>
<div class="canvas_div_pdf" style="margin-left:100px;">
<p> {{ Something from Django }}</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

I tried to use it in a form and nothing changed.

Comment: Something logged in console? Any chance you can build a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: For the console, it's the same when it worked without the Django variable.

Comment: Is the rendered HTML as expected? ID correct, content just in the p as expected, such stuff? If it is, django shouldn't be relevant anymore

pls post the generated HTML snippet

Comment: I already did, I tried with that basic snippet, the first one worked, but with Django variable, didn't work

Comment: we can only help you with some more django code ^^'

Open the website, go to source code in browser, scroll to the snippet and copy that here

Comment: can't help without the required information, also.. bro isn't correct for everyone ;)